# C++ Armadillo: mat initialization from vector<vector<double>> destroys data

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm trying to initialize data from a vector of vectors to armadillo mat.

found this site explaining how to do it:

http://www.kaiyin.co.vu/2014/07/initialize-armadillo-matrix-with-std.html

after printing the vector of vectors  and the resulting mat i came to the conclusion  that armadillo makes garbage of my data.

the main part of my function:

```
 vector<vector<double>> C_mat(num_of_functions,vector<double>(num_of_points));
        for(int j=0; j< num_of_functions; ++j)
        {
            for( int i=0;i<num_of_points; ++i)
            {
                C_mat[j][i]=(functions[j](points[i].x()));// shouldn't bother you, this works. 
            }
        }
        mat C(&(C_mat.front()).front(),num_of_points, num_of_functions);

        cout << C << endl << endl;
        for(int i=0; i< num_of_functions;++i)
        {
            print_vec(C_mat[i]);
        }
```

print_ve(vector) is a function i wrote that prints a vector.

output:

```
    1.0000e+00        0e+00   1.9965e+01
    1.0000e+00  4.7924e-322   1.2822e+00
    1.0000e+00   1.1683e+01        0e+00
    1.0000e+00   1.6936e+01  4.7924e-322
    1.0000e+00   2.3361e-01   1.0237e+02
    1.0000e+00   1.6445e+01   2.1512e+02
    1.0000e+00   7.4271e+00   4.0931e-02
    1.0000e+00   1.4162e+01   2.0284e+02
    1.0000e+00   1.1670e+01   4.1371e+01
    1.0000e+00   2.3633e+00   1.5042e+02
```

printing vector:

1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

printing vector:

11.6828
16.9359
0.233613
16.4455
7.42708
14.1619
11.6701
2.36329
19.9653
1.28223

printing vector:

102.366
215.119
0.0409313
202.84
41.3711
150.421
102.143
4.18885
298.959
1.23308

UPDATE:

I tried changing the code with respect to the first comment by essentially making my own 2D vector out of 1D vector. now armadillo does not destroy the data but scrambles it:

```
        vector<double> C_mat(num_of_functions*num_of_points);   
        for( int i=0;i<num_of_points; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j< num_of_functions; ++j)
            {
                    C_mat[i*num_of_functions+j]= functions[j](points[i].x());
            }
        } 
        mat C(&C_mat.front(),num_of_points, num_of_functions);
```

output:

```
     1.0000e+00   1.1170e+01   1.6853e+01
     4.5538e+00   9.3574e+01   1.0000e+00
     1.5553e+01   1.0000e+00   1.6292e+01
     1.0000e+00   8.7956e-01   1.9907e+02
     6.0653e+00   5.8021e-01   1.0000e+00
     2.7591e+01   1.0000e+00   1.0787e+01
     1.0000e+00   1.8169e+01   8.7269e+01
     1.3849e+01   2.4758e+02   1.0000e+00
     1.4385e+02   1.0000e+00   1.7998e+01
     1.0000e+00   4.7403e+00   2.4295e+02


   1  4.5538  15.5528 
   1  6.06532  27.5911 
   1  13.8494  143.854 
   1  11.1698  93.574 
   1  0.879557  0.580215 
   1  18.1687  247.577 
   1  4.74031  16.8529 
   1  16.2919  199.069 
   1  10.787  87.2695 
   1  17.998  242.945
```

Comment: Armadillo doesn't scramble anything. Your original data is in row major order. Armadillo stores data in column major order, for compatibility with LAPACK. You passed a pointer to your original data while not taking into account that the rows and columns have interchanged. This might work better: `mat C(&C_mat.front(), num_of_functions, num_of_points, false);`. To transpose the matrix, use [.t()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#t_st_members) or [trans()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#trans) functions.

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `std::vector` is equivalient a data pointer and a length (and some irrelevant stuff). The pointer points to a bunch of memory, where the actual elements are stored. 0th element is stored at the address `pointer`, Nth element is stored at `pointer+N`. That is why the Armadillo mat constructor can take the adress of the first element and a length and construct a matrix.

When you make a vector you get `num_of_functions` inner vectors, each with their own data pointer. This means that the data is not stored in contiguous memory.

To initialize a 2-D matrix for `std::vector` you should create your matrix with size `num_of_functions*num_of_points` and store the values in column-major-ordering.